# Brennan-Schwartz algorithm for pricing American options

Tags: american-options, numerical-methods, black-scholes-pde, finite-difference-method

I'm reading [Pricing American Options using LU decomposition](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.62.1248&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Ikonen and 
Toivanen (IT).

They reference [The valuation of American put options](http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/thesis/BrSch.AmrPut.pdf) by Brennan and Schwartz, and cast it as method that uses LU decomposition to solve the linear complementarity problem (LCP) arising in the discretisation of the Black-Scholes "PDI" for American options.

On page 9, IT write:

"It is obvious that the use of the max-function in the backward substitution is possible because of the form of the solution of the option pricing problem."

Does this mean that the Brennan-Schwartz method of modified back substitution exactly the LCP exactly? If so, I don't think this is *obvious*. Is there a proof of it anywhere?

And on a related note, if Brennan-Schwartz solves the LCP exactly then why doesn't Wilmott use it in his "The Mathematics of Financial Derivatives"? He uses Projected Successive Over-relaxation (PSOR) exclusively, which is shown by IT to be a lot slower than using LU decomposition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ikonen and Toivanen don't say that the LCP is solved exactly, they simply say that the modified back-substitution is a valid algorithm to solve the LCP.

A numerical error may arise around the location of optimal exercise, since it does not fall directly on the finite difference grid. I think that however, the error is of the same order as the discretization in space.

Incidentally, PSOR and the modified back-substitution are both presented in Elliot and Ockendon *Weak and Variational Methods for Free Moving Boundary Problems*, which is referenced by Ikonen and Toivanen.

The interest of PSOR is to be more general: there is some monotonicity condition that must be verified in order to apply the Brennan-Schwartz algorithm. So it is perfectly fine for a vanilla American put or call, but not for an American butterfly.